# Storybook using children as an arg thorws an error 'bound Template cannot be used as component'

Tags: reactjs, next.js, storybook, emotion

According to Storybook's doc:
https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/workflows/stories-for-multiple-components

```
// List.stories.ts | List.stories.tsx

import React from 'react';

import { List, ListProps } from './List';

// Instead of importing ListItem, we import the stories
import { Unchecked } from './ListItem.stories';

const Template: Story<ListProps> = (args) => <List {...args} />;

export const OneItem = Template.bind({});
OneItem.args = {
  children: <Unchecked {...Unchecked.args} />,
};
```

Stories can be used for children just like React elements.

However my code follows the doc example but throws an error below.

`bound Template cannot be used as component.`

My code:

```
// checkFormField.stories.tsx

import { Meta, Story } from '@storybook/react';
import CheckFormField from '@components/old/signup/organisms/checkFormField/index';
import { CheckboxProps } from '@components/old/signup/molecules/checkbox/interfaces';

// Instead of importing ListItem, we import the stories
import {DefaultCheckbox} from '@components/old/signup/molecules/checkbox/checkbox.stories';

export default {
  title: 'checkFormField',
  component: CheckFormField,
} as Meta;

const Template: Story = (args) => <CheckFormField {...args}/>

export const OneItem = Template.bind({})
OneItem.args = {
  children: [<DefaultCheckbox {...DefaultCheckbox.args as CheckboxProps}/>]
}
```

```
// checkbox.stories.tsx

import { Meta, Story } from '@storybook/react';
import Checkbox from '@components/old/signup/molecules/checkbox/index';
import { CheckboxProps } from '@components/old/signup/molecules/checkbox/interfaces';

export default {
  title: 'checkbox',
  component: Checkbox,
} as Meta;

const Template: Story<CheckboxProps> = (args) => <Checkbox {...args} />;

export const DefaultCheckbox = Template.bind({});

DefaultCheckbox.args = {
  id: 'test',
  labelText: 'Default Checkbox',
  tabIndex: 0,
  checked: false,
  isDiners: false,
};
```

I know that the caveats says below:

- ```
  Avoid using empty values
  ```
- ```
  Use caution with components that include third party libraries
  ```

**As they could lead into errors with your Storybook.**

but I just wanted to know that if I miss something and the way to implement.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So did you ever figure out how to pass children in storybook arguments?

Answer (score 2):

In my case, [mappings](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/writing-stories/args#mapping-to-complex-arg-values) were what I needed (Storybook 6.2+):

`Text.stories.tsx`

```
const meta: Meta<typeof Text> = {
  title: "Text",
  component: Text,
  argTypes: {
    children: {
      options: ['Normal', 'Bold', 'Italic'],
      mapping: {
        Normal: <span>Normal</span>,
        Bold: <b>Bold</b>,
        Italic: <i>Italic</i>,
      },
    },
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use an Array:

```
  args: {
    otherArg: 'hello',
    children: [
      <div className="h-24 rounded-lg shadow-lg bg-violet-400" />,
      <div className="h-24 rounded-lg shadow-lg bg-orange-400" />,
      <div className="h-24 rounded-lg shadow-lg bg-red-400" />,
      <div className="h-24 rounded-lg shadow-lg bg-blue-400" />,
      <div className="h-24 rounded-lg shadow-lg bg-green-400" />
    ]
  }
```