How do I create a Story for a React component that wraps HTML in Storybook?
I'm new to React and have been trying to Google a solution to this for hours - I probably just don't know the right terminology.
I know I can create a Story for a React component by importing the component and setting it's arguments as such:
import Button from './button';

export default {
  title: 'Atoms/button',
  component: Button,
  parameters: {
    layout: 'centered',
  },
  tags: ['autodocs'],
};

export const Standard = {
  args: {
     label: "Click me",
     size: "lg"
  },
};

But how do I create a story for a component that wraps HTML (or another component), eg Tippy Tooltips:
<Tooltip
  title="Welcome to React"
  position="bottom"
  trigger="click"
>
  <p>Click here to show popup</p>
</Tooltip>

How to I send <p>Click here to show popup</p> as an arg in Storybook?

The html you want to use as an argument is a child of Tooltip. Please, check a following thread for instance: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68858334/storybook-using-children-as-an-arg-thorws-an-error-bound-template-cannot-be-use
